# JOLT : Convert one property of an array into a comma separated string

Tags: arrays, jolt

USING JOLT

I need to convert the names in the tags array into a comma separated string set as tag.

Input:

```
tags : [
{
"id" : "1",
"name": "mobile",
"slug": ""
},
{
"id" : "2",
"name": "smart phone",
"slug": ""
},
{
"id" : "3",
"name": "light-weight",
"slug": ""
}
]
```

OUTPUT:

> tags : "mobile, smart-phone, light-weight"

What should be the expected spec?

Answer (score 2):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "tags": {
        "*": {
          "name": "tags.[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the output must be Json would be:

```
{
  "tags" : [ "mobile", "smart phone", "light-weight" ]
}
```

Comment: @Behrouz Seyedi the required output is a comma separated string and not an array of strings.

Comment: How to reverse of above transformation? From list of strings to list of map/dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

This way.

```
[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "tags": {
    "*": {
      "name": "tags.[]"
    }
  }
 }
},
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
  "tags": "=join(',',@(1,tags))"
  }
 }
]
```

just use the method join to comma-separated the fields